# Regex to remove character before a character set

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have dataframe with column 'code'.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'code': ['10SGD35/AA501/10SGD35/AA599/10SGD36/AA501/10SGD36AA599/10SGD37/AA501/10SGD37/AA527',
                            '10SGD08/AA701/10SGD08/AA704/10SGD09/AA701/10SGD09AA708']})
```

How can I drop character '/' before character set 'AA' in pandas?

```
                                                                            code
0  10SGD35AA501/10SGD35AA599/10SGD36AA501/10SGD36AA599/10SGD37AA501/10SGD37AA527
1                            10SGD08AA701/10SGD08AA704/10SGD09AA701/10SGD09AA708
```

I use [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
df['data'] = df['data'].str.replace('|(?=AA)', '', regex=True)
```

This regex does not work. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Just use a substitution `\/AA/AA/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex with a lookahead and [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['code'] = df['code'].str.replace('/(?=AA)', '', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
                                                                            code   text
0  10SGD35AA501/10SGD35AA599/10SGD36AA501/10SGD36AA599/10SGD37AA501/10SGD37AA527  text1
1                            10SGD08AA701/10SGD08AA704/10SGD09AA701/10SGD09AA708  text2
```

###### regex

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NHoEwI/1)

```
/       # match "/"
(?=AA)  # only if followed by "AA"
```